# Como importar los sdk de une eclipse a otro

Tags: eclipse

el problema es que hace poco mi eclipse el cual usaba habitualmente me dejo de funcionar. Entonces decidi bajarme otro pero no incluye todos los sdk, platform tools y cosas que descargue.

Mi pegunta es hay alguna manera de importar todos los sdk de mi antiguo eclipse a mi nuevo eclipse?

Es para no estar descargando todo nuevo ya que al menos necesitare la virtual de android device 2.2 y la 4.4.4.

Comment: Estan en la carpeta .m2 ahi tienes todos los jar que has utilizado

Comment: pero los puedo importar a mi otro eclipse como seria en que parte?

Comment: Pero el otro eclipse es en otro computadora?? que sistema operativo usas??

Comment: windows 10 es el que uso

Comment: entonces la carpeta esta oculta pero puedes activar para ver las **carpetas ocultas** y la ruta `c:\Users\(nombre de tu usuario)\.m2`